# css3 transitions - How to make a div grow in height from bottom to top

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, transition

I am trying to make the following to work in IE10.

I have a div with `id=footer` for whom I am changing the class from `class1` to `class2`.

The HTML code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="class1"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code is as follows

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:  100%;
    height:  100%;
}

#container {
    overflow:  auto;
    position: absolute;
    width:  100%;
    height:  90%;
    background-color:#808080;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: groove;
}

#footer {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color:#f00;
    border-style: groove;
    background-color: #ffd800;

    transition-property: top, height;
    transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
    transition-delay: 0, 0;
}

.class1 {
    top: 90%;
    height: 10%;
}

.class2 {
    top: 70%;
    height: 30%;
}
```

Since I am simultaneously increasing both top and height, I expect the div to just riseup/expand when I am changing from `class1 to class2` and just contract when changing from `class2 to class1`. This works as expected in Firefox.

But in IE10, when I change from `class1 to class2`, it is as if the transition effects are not obeyed for `top`. The div immediately shifts up and then the size gradually increases over 1 second.

So, how do I solve this problem and get the expected results in IE10?

Comment: Works fine for me in IE 10.0.9200.16618 (10.0.6 KB2838727) on Windows 7 x64. What are your specs? Also have you removed anything from your example that might affect the behaviour?

Comment: My version is IE 10.0.9200.16599 (10.0.6 KB2838727). The only difference is that #footer was not a div in my original code, it was an iframe. but, I don't think that should make any difference.

Comment: Are you using Windows 8? If so, which variant of IE are you using, Desktop or Modern UI?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't experience in IE11 the dynamics you described.
Perhaps a solution would be to first set the height to 30% before changing the top.